# Автоматически добавляются объекты PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Есть несколько классов, которые взаимодействуют между собой.

Класс `School` должен создавать объект, например, `Школа №13`, который содержит массив объектов класса `SchoolClasses`.

Экземпляры класса `SchoolClasses` должны содержать в себе данные школьных классов (название класса, массив объектов класса Students(ученики)).

Мое решение:

**School class:**

```
class School extends SchoolClasses
{
    private $school_name;
    private $school_classes = array();

    function __construct($name)
    {
      $this->school_name = $name;
    }

    public function addClass($class_name)
    {
      array_push($this->school_classes, new SchoolClasses($class_name));
    }

    public function getClassData()
    {
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($this->school_classes);
      echo '</pre>';
    }

    public function addStudent($class_id, $classmate_name, $classmate_age)
    {
      return $this->school_classes[$class_id]->setStudent(
        new Students($classmate_name, $classmate_age);
      );
    }
}
```

**SchoolClasses class:**

```
class SchoolClasses extends Students
{
  private $class_name;
  private $class_students_array = array();

  public function __construct($name)
  {
    $this->class_name = $name;
  }

  public function setStudent($student)
  {
    return array_push($this->class_students_array, $student);
  }
}
```

**Students class**

```
class Students
{
  private $student_name;
  private $student_age;

  public function __construct($name, $age)
  {
    $this->student_name = $name;
    $this->student_age = $age;
  }
}
```

**main.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'class/School.class.php';

$school_13 = new School("Школа 13");
$school_13->addClass("1В");
$school_13->addClass("2A");

$school_13->getClassData();
$school_13->addStudent(0, "Вася", 7);
$school_13->getClassData();

?>
```

Вот что выдает `$school->getClassData()`:

До добавления школьных классов:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SchoolClasses Object
        (
            [class_name:SchoolClasses:private] => 1В
            [class_students_array:SchoolClasses:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [student_name:Students:private] => # Здесь
            [student_age:Students:private] => # Здесь
        )

    [1] => SchoolClasses Object
        (
            [class_name:SchoolClasses:private] => 2A
            [class_students_array:SchoolClasses:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [student_name:Students:private] => # Здесь
            [student_age:Students:private] => # Здесь
        )

)
```

После:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SchoolClasses Object
        (
            [class_name:SchoolClasses:private] => 1В
            [class_students_array:SchoolClasses:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Students Object
                        (
                            [student_name:Students:private] => Вася
                            [student_age:Students:private] => 7
                        )

                )

            [student_name:Students:private] => # Здесь
            [student_age:Students:private] => # Здесь
        )

    [1] => SchoolClasses Object
        (
            [class_name:SchoolClasses:private] => 2A
            [class_students_array:SchoolClasses:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [student_name:Students:private] => # Здесь
            [student_age:Students:private] => # Здесь
        )

)
```

Не могу понять, откуда берутся записи `[student_name:Students:private]` и `[student_age:Students:private]`, ведь я их в массив не добавляю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина в наследовании. У вас класс `SchoolClasses` почему-то наследуется от `Students`:

```
class SchoolClasses extends Students
```

Поэтому в классе `SchoolClasses` есть параметры, которые он наследует от `Students`:

```
private $student_name;
private $student_age;
```

Видимо, ошибочно наследование написали. Уберите и всё будет как задумано.